# How To Build Strongly Typed XML POST Request With Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, restsharp

I have to make an XML Request. I'm wondering how to create an XML request that has a node with attributes. Here is an example of a working request I've tried out in Postman.

```
        <ItemDestination DestinationType="geocode" Longitude="0.1278" Latitude="51.5074" RadiusKm="100"/>
```

In the XML Request I have to make, the node ItemDestination has several attributes like "lattitude" and "longitude." Here is the class that the tool XML2C# turned the xml into:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemDestination")]
    public class ItemDestination
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DestinationType")]
        public string DestinationType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Longitude")]
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Latitude")]
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RadiusKm")]
        public string RadiusKm { get; set; }
    }
```

now when I make the call instead of the node having attributes like I want, when I open a fiddler and check out the request it looks like this:

```
    <ItemDestination>
        <DestinationType>geocode</DestinationType>
        <Longitude>2.64663399999995</Longitude>
        <Latitude>39.57119</Latitude>
        <RadiusKm>5</RadiusKm>
    </ItemDestination>
```

Which is not what I want. So how do I edit the class to turn the above request into the following request?

```
<ItemDestination DestinationType="geocode" Longitude="0.1278" Latitude="51.5074" RadiusKm="100"/>
```

Serialization Code:

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GTASearchRequest).ToString());
    var xmlRequest = serializer.Serialize(request);
```

Comment: The class is correct if you use XmlSerializer to generate the XML. I suspect you are using something else - maybe DataContractSerializer?

Comment: hi MiMo, i posted teh serialization code...I'm using XMLSerializer

Comment: It does not look like the Microsoft XmlSerializer class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx (the constructor expects a type, not a string, and Serialize has two parameters)

Comment: you are right, but that method involves creating an xml file everytime I want to make an http request....

Comment: I don't think it's a serialization issue, should i be using xml node in my class def anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
        var data = new ItemDestination
        {
            DestinationType = "geocode",
            Longitude = "2.64663399999995",
            Latitude = "39.57119",
            RadiusKm = "5"
        };

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( ItemDestination ) );
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        serializer.Serialize( writer, data );
        writer.Flush();
        var xmlRequest = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

where `ItemDestination` is declared as:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemDestination")]
public class ItemDestination
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DestinationType")]
    public string DestinationType { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Longitude")]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Latitude")]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RadiusKm")]
    public string RadiusKm { get; set; }
}
```

produce the desired string in `xmlRequest`

Comment: so DestinationType, Longitude, Latitude, and RadiusKm are internal classes?

Comment: they are string - the definition of the `ItemDestination` class is exactly the same as in the question